# Is there a way to dynamically create X-Axis annotations on Apex line chart?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

Is there a way to dynamically create X-axis annotations on an [Apex line chart](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/line-charts/line-chart-annotations/)? The example in the demo (see above link) shows static, hard-coded annotations.

At first I thought I could loop through the data and call the `updateOptions` method for each item, but that doesn't work, since each time I call that method, I'm overwriting whichever annotation was added on the previous iteration of the loop.

It seems like I should be able to use the [addXaxisAnnotation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#addxaxisannotation) method instead per this [discussion](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/1180), but I'm not seeing the annotations appear on the

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Mickey_Vershbow/pen/poaKGNd) that recreates the problem. There's an array of mock data to populate the chart with, as well as an array of "markers" i.e. annotations. I'm creating the empty chart, and then updating it with annotations and data.

Here's an example of how I'm trying to use the `addXaxisAnnotation` method.

```
// A bunch of code to create the line chart goes here

// List of "markers" i.e. annotations
let markerList = [
  {
    name: "Pre Season 1",
    period_begin: "2020-11-01"
  },
  {
    name: "Episodes 1-3",
    period_begin: "2020-11-26"
  },
  {
    name: "Episodes 4-5",
    period_begin: "2020-12-03"
  },
  {
    name: "Episodes 6-7",
    period_begin: "2020-12-10"
  },
  {
    name: "Episode 8",
    period_begin: "2020-12-17"
  },
  {
    name: "Post Season 1",
    period_begin: "2020-12-24"
  }
];

markerList.forEach((item) => {
    chart.addXaxisAnnotation({
      x: new Date(`${item.period_begin}`).getTime(),
        text: `${item.name}`
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: The codepen: https://codepen.io/Mickey_Vershbow/pen/poaKGNd

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put this code in the "update" function and use the "exec" method to call the "addXaxisAnnotation" function like so:

```
markerList.forEach((item) => {
    ApexCharts.exec("posts-over-time-chart", "addXaxisAnnotation", {
      x: new Date(`${item.period_begin}`).getTime(),
      label: {
        text: `${item.name}`,
      },
    });
  });
```